# Why does modulo 100 stop returning a two digit date this year?

Tags: c#

So this worked for the last few years:

```
int currentYear = new DateTime().Year % 100;
```

But this year instead of 18 it returns 1.

I've fixed it with a different bit of code but why did it suddenly stop working? What's special about 2018?

Edit: Typo in the code provided to me, should have checked it myself. Lesson learned. Thanks to those who answered and feel free to delete / close the question.

Comment: `new DateTime()` returns `0001-01-01 00:00:00`. You want `DateTime.Now` or `DateTime.Today`

Comment: your code never worked, so the real question should be 'Why did this code return 17 instead of 1 last year?'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because

```
int year = new DateTime().Year;
```

returns `1`. This behaviour is described in the [Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime?view=netframework-4.7):

```
DateTime dat1 = new DateTime();
// The following method call displays 1/1/0001 12:00:00 AM.
Console.WriteLine(dat1.ToString(System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture));
// The following method call displays True.
Console.WriteLine(dat1.Equals(DateTime.MinValue));
```

To get the year you need to use the current time. Use

```
int currentYear = DateTime.Now.Year % 100;
```

to solve your problem.

Comment: you should explain why new DateTime.Year returns 1